# Is there a more efficient way of returning a hash value given array of keys if hash key/value is present?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a method which accepts a hash, and I have an array of keys (ordered by preference) which I want to check the hash for and return the value of the first matching key that's found which is not `blank?`. So far I have the following, but since I utilize this method heavily, I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way of going about it?

```
result = [:title, :name, :identifier, :slug].each do |key|
            if my_hash[key].present?
              return my_hash[key]
              break
            end
          end
```

So given the following hash:

```
{
  id: 10,
  title: "",
  name: "Foo",
  slug: "foo"
}
```

I would expect `result` to be: "Foo"

Comment: Your wrote that you want a key/value pair, but your code only returns the value. Which do you really want?

Comment: Edited for clarity - I want the value of the first key that's found given the ordered list of keys. Hashes may have some or all keys and sometimes a hash may have a key, but not a value (or rather not a `truthy` value)

Comment: Along the lines of your code, you can also do `break my_hash[key]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your way is probably close to the best from the point of view of efficiency. But if you want it to be more elegant, retaining the efficiency, then:

```
my_hash[%i[title name identifier slug].find{|key| my_hash[key].present?}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
whitelisted_keys = [:title, :name, :identifier, :slug]
filtered_hash = your_hash.slice(*whitelisted_keys) # will only get pair matching your whitelisted_keys

# return all `.present?` key/values pairs:
filtered_hash.select{ |k,v| v.present? }

# return an array of the first key/value pair present:
filtered_hash.find{ |k,v| v.present? } # append .last to get the value
```

As Sawa pointed out in the comment, this is not the most efficient way but might be more "readable"

Comment: Nice! I was trying to figure out how to use `slice` but it was your `*whitelisted_keys` that I was missing. How about: `your_hash[your_hash.slice(*whitelisted_keys).keys.first]`?

Comment: well that would just return the value for the first whitelisted key, which might not be `present?`

Comment: This may be elegant, but is less efficient than the OPs. You are creating an intermediate hash. Also, you are calling a Rails method `slice`, which makes the code less efficient.

Comment: @sawa very good point, I usualy prefer readability but as OP asked, he is looking for the most efficient way to achieve this.